# how to display if customer has a single transaction or multiple transactions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to ask a question on how to correctly display single or multiple transactions if a user has more than one purchase from different stores in day. If a user bought once it will display "single" and if the user bought more than once it will display "multiple"

[image: excel worksheet]

For reference, column F is for determining if the user bought more than once, 0= first transaction and 1= other transactions. If a user has only 0 and no 1s then it is considered single transaction only. I tried using this formula in column H:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,
    IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,D$2:D2,D2)>1,
        OFFSET(A$2,MATCH(A2&D2,$A$2:A2&A2&$D$2:D2,0)-1,1),
        MAX(IF($A1:A$2=A2,$F1:F$2))+1))
```

but, it was not showing the result I want.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to reference columns B and C instead? `=--(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2,$B2,$C$2:$C2,$C2)>1)` or `=IF((COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2,$B2,$C$2:$C2,$C2)>1),"multiple","single")`

Comment: Hello,

thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried both formulas but it didn't show the result i'm expecting. both formulas just categorized the consumers into single and for the first one it just displayed 0 all through.

Comment: Could you also post expected results? You may want to use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# for posting data. And you should use dummy data, not actual emails etc.

Comment: You shouldn't show private information, such as sections of email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it should be possible to use SUMPRODUCT to accomplish this.

Try: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A2),--(D:D=D2))>1,"mutiple","single")`